# Flutter Textformfield prefix text

Tags: flutter, textformfield, flutter-textformfield

I am trying to create a textformfield with a prefix text that looks the images below. This one is before entering any text

[image: textformfield 1]

and this is after entering text

[image: 2]

This is the code I have written

```
                TextFormField(
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    prefixIcon: Text(
                      '+254',
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                      style: theme.textTheme.bodyText2!.copyWith(
                          color: Color(0xff000000),
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
                    ),
                    hintText: getTranslated(context, "label_hint")!,
                    hintStyle: theme.textTheme.bodyText2!.copyWith(
                      color: primaryLight.withOpacity(0.75),
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                    ),
                    fillColor: const Color(0xffF5F5F5),
                    enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderSide:
                          const BorderSide(width: 1, color: Color(0xffCCCCCC)),
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
                    ),
                    focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderSide: const BorderSide(width: 1, color: Color(0xffF38E30)),
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
```

This is how my attempt looks
[image: 3]

I'd like to achieve something close to the first two images, what can I change in my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try wrapping the text widget in `prefixIcon: Text('+254',` with a column, and give its main axis alignment a center. Or wrap your text widget with a `Center` widget.

Answer (score 2):

Wrap `Text` widget in a `Row` widget and assign it's `mainAxisSize` property to `MainAxisSize.min` and `mainAxisAlignment` property to `mainAxisAlignment.center` to achieve the prefixText inline with hint text

try this code -

```
   TextFormField(
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        prefixIcon: Row(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: const [
            Text(
              '+254',
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.black,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        hintText: 'mobile number',
        hintStyle: const TextStyle(
          color: Colors.grey,
          fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
        ),
        fillColor: const Color(0xffF5F5F5),
        enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
          borderSide:
              const BorderSide(width: 1, color: Color(0xffCCCCCC)),
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
        ),
        focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
          borderSide:
              const BorderSide(width: 1, color: Color(0xffF38E30)),
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
        ),
      ),
    ),
```

[image]